Java CopyOnWriteArrayList add element if not exists already
I have an CopyOnWriteArrayList as my code should be thread safe.
List friuts = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
I don't want to have duplicate friuts in list I cannot use Set as I want to have insertion order as well. I have written this code
public boolean add(String friut) {
    synchronized (friuts) {
        if (friuts.contains(friut)) {
            return false;
        }
        friuts.add(friut);
    }
    return true;
}

As I know is CopyOnWriteArrayList already concurrent. So adding CopyOnWriteArrayList.add within synchronized block doesn't seems to be a good idea to me. Is there any other better solution?

a LinkedHashSet maintains insertion order.

rzwitserloot is right, you should be using LinkedHashSet for this.

CopyOnWriteArraySet promises insertion order in its iterator.

While CopyOnWriteArrayList is concurrent, it is designed for usecases where updates are rare.  If updates are common enough that the overheads of a synchronized method for updates is a concern ... you have a bigger problem than overheads of that method!

Use the addIfAbsent() method:
CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> fruits = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

public boolean add(String fruit) {
    fruits.addIfAbsent(fruit);
}


Thanks, I was looking List interface that's why I missed this method. Anyways thanks a lot
@shmosel :-)
